# Go: Unexpected performance when accessing an array through slice of slices (2D slice)

Tags: performance, memory-management, optimization, multidimensional-array, go

I was doing some performance experimentation in Go with matrix multiplication and ran into some unexpected results.

Version 1:

```
func newMatrix(n int) [][]int {
    m := make([][]int, n)
    buf := make([]int, n*n)

    for i := range m {
        m[i] = buf[i*n : (i+1)*n]
    }

    return m
}

func mult1(m1, m2, res [][]int) [][]int {
    for i := range m1 {
        for k := range m1[0] {
            for j := range m2[0] {
                res[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j]
            }
        }
    }

    return res
}
```

From the linear array i create multiple slices that represent the matrix rows.

Version 2:

```
func mult2(m1, m2, res []int, n int) []int {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        for k := 0; k < n; k++ {
            for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
                res[i*n+j] += m1[i*n+k] * m2[k*n+j]
            }
        }
    }

    return res
}
```

In this version I simply use a linear array and index into it from the multiplication.

Multiplying 2 2048x2048 matrices give the following execution time:

```
 version 1: 35.550813801s
 version 2: 19.090223468s
```

Version 2 is almost twice as fast.

I used the approach below to take the measurements:

```
start := time.Now()
mult(m1, m2, m3)
stop := time.Now()
```

I am aware using slices give another layer of indirection which could impact the cache performance, however I didn't expect it would be such a big difference. Unfortunately I haven't found any good tool, that works with Mac, that can analyse cache efficiency in Go, so I can't say for sure if this is what's causing the performance difference.

So I guess I'm asking is this expected behavior or is there something I'm missing?

Software and hardware:
Go version 1.4.2 darwin/amd64; OS X 10.10.3; 2 GHz quad-core i7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem in your version 1 code seems to be *indirect addressing*. Even though the layout in memory for the matrices in both versions is the same, using indirect addressing can lead to:

- *More generated instructions for the same code.* The compiler could have trouble in determining when to use packed versions of SIMD instructions (e.g. SSE, AVX). You can verify this by dumping the assembly code, look for XMM or YMM registers and check if the instructions operating on the registers are packed.
- *You make it difficult for the compiler to add software prefetches.* Because indirect addressing, it's difficult for the compiler to detect how to add software prefetches. You can look for vprefetch instructions in the assembly code.
- *The hardware prefetcher will be less efficient* also due to indirect addressing. You first need to access the line start address and then access the line elements so it's hard to observe that the hardware prefetcher should just fetch consecutive addresses. That's only measurable through profiling like perf.

So in case of version 1, *indirect addressing* is the main issue. I also recommend running the 2 codes in multiple iterations to r*emove the cache warming penalty* which might be higher for version 1 because of what I explained above.

Comment: Quick follow-up regarding your first point: the matrix is stored the same way in memory in both cases, i.e. as a 1D array. The only difference is in how I access it. In version 1 I use 2D slices and in version 2 I use a linear slice.I'm also not experiencing such big performance differences in other languages, e.g. Java. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: There's a difference between using [][]int and []int. The second case means that the array is stored contiguously (1D). The first I consider 2D and you have to pay all the mentioned penalties. There's a chance that Java might make just in time optimizations and change your code on the fly, so the performance differences won't be major.

Comment: If you look at the code of version 1 you see that I allocate one big n*n array, and then create slices for each row that point to this linear array.

Comment: Hmmm... That's a point. What do you include in timing? Do you also include the allocation? If not, that leaves only causes 2 and 3. Because of the indirection you add more cycles per transaction and make the hw prefetcher ineffective.

Comment: The measurements doesn't include any allocations. I'm gonna do some more testing in Java before I'll accept this as answered.

Comment: The most straight forward solution would be to have the assembly code posted for mult1 and mult2 and look at the differences.

Comment: I implemented something similar to Go slices in C which made it clearer were the performance penalty came from. Thanks for your answer, although you should probably remove / edit your first bullet.

Comment: Please see my revised response. If you have a linux machine, you can run your program with "perf stat ./binary" and you will see a bunch of statistics that will give you the reasons for the performance difference.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to put this in as comment, but in addition to *VAndrei*'s points it is worth noting that two provided examples use for-loop differently. How does first example perform after `s/i := range m1/i := 0; i < n; i++/` ?

It could also be useful to check how "list mult1" and "list mult2" outputs looks like in pprof.
There is great tutorial to get started with Go's pprof very fast: [Profiling Go Programs By Russ Cox](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs)